# Java Maven assembly plugin Fatal error compiling: invalid target release 1.14

Tags: java, maven, javafx, maven-assembly-plugin

I want to use the maven assembly plugin to deploy my javafx project in Intellij but whenever I try to do it, I get

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Battlesheet: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 1.14 -> [Help 1]
```

as a result. My pom is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.Avalon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Battlesheet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Avalon Battlesheet</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.14</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>15-ea+6</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>15-ea+6</version>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>15-ea+6</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>15-ea+6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>assembly.Launcher</mainClass>
                    <launcher>launch.sh</launcher>
                    <compress>2</compress>
                    <jlinkZipName>avalon-battlesheet</jlinkZipName>
                    <jlinkImageName>avalon-battlesheet</jlinkImageName>
                    <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                    <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-executable</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${test.pack.dir}</outputDirectory>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>assembly.Launcher</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I know there are a lot of questions like this already up, but I read through at least most of them to no avail. My path and JAVA_HOME are both set to my only JDK (AdoptOpenJDK 1.14) my project structure should all be set to 1.14 whereever I can and now my knowledge fails, why it still tells me I have an invalid target release. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: try with the maven-compiler plugin: https://mkyong.com/maven/maven-error-invalid-target-release-1-11/

Comment: Because `1.14` is not a valid target indeed. After Java `8` the `1.` was dropped. Java `1.14` _does not exist_. Further, Maven always supported the `X` rather than `1.X` syntax anyway. TL;DR: `14` not `1.14`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to build with Java 14. The prefixes (aka `1.`) aren't used anymore, so try changing `1.14` to `14`.